# AngularJS: All elements using directive show same value

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which passes a reference to the scope data through an attribute like so (assuming `$scope.parent.child` exists): 
`<span status-label item='parent.child'></span>`

The directive works as expected when used once. But when used more than once, and with different `item` attribute values, all elements using the directive show the same value.

My full code is below and a Plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9ahmua?p=preview. If you'll notice, changing the `item=` value on the second element using the directive (line 8) will change the value for all elements to that value.

What am I doing incorrectly? How do I make each element / directive work off of its individual `item` attribute? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='familyApp'>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller='BaseController'>
      <p>{{ parent.child.name }}: <span status-label item='parent.child'></span></p>
      <p>{{ root.name }}: <span status-label item='root'></span></p>
    </div>
  </body>
    <script data-require="jquery@1.7.1" data-semver="1.7.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.12" data-require="angular.js@1.2.12"></script>
    <script>
    var familyApp = angular.module('familyApp', []);
      angular.module('familyApp').controller('BaseController',
        function ($scope) {
          $scope.root = {
            name: 'Jack',
            age: 40,
            flagged: false
          };   
          $scope.parent = {
            child: {
              name: 'Jill',
              age: 30,
              flagged: true
            }
          };          
        });
      angular.module('familyApp').directive('statusLabel',
        function ($compile, $parse) {
            return {
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    scope.status = function (item) {
                        item = $parse(element.attr('item'))(scope);
                        if (item.flagged === true) {
                          return 'flagged';
                        }
                        return 'clean';
                    };
                },
                transclude: true,
                template: '<div ng-switch on="status()"><div ng-switch-when="flagged">Flagged</div><div ng-switch-when="clean">Clean</div></div>'
            };
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to give the directive it's own scope by setting scope to something.

You can learn more about that [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope)